# Javascript regular expression for URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me with building regular expression to extract couple of URLS using regular expressions from the below string

```
'<a href="http://mydmncd.app.corp:8080/ag/ps?q=C~0~0~0~0~0~v2hgsds4-0Ds43Hg~94~0~~~1~0~0~~http%3a%2f%2fnghj.com" target="_blank"><img border=0   
src="mydmncd.app.png" ALT="" clickUrl="http://mydmncd.app2.corp?q=1&f=4"/></a>'
```

Url always starts with `http://mydmncd` and the remaining part may vary. I have to extract the url until I find double quotes. In the above example I have to extract `http://mydmncd.app.corp:8080/ag/ps?q=C~0~0~0~0~0~v2hgsds4-0Ds43Hg~94~0~~~1~0~0~~http%3a%2f%2fnghj.com`

I tried with this regex  `/[http://mydmncd].*"/g`  but it is matching the last double quotes. I have also tried `/[http://mydmncd].*\s/g` but no luck.

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKEh8/3/)

Comment: I assume that you are not actually dealing with strings here, but with `<a>` elements somewhere in your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.*` also matches the `"`.

You should be able to replace `.*` by `[^\"]*` to match any character except `"`.

I don't have any way to test here, hope that can help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't vote. SO says I need min 15 reputation to vote :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to capture it as a sub-expression which can later be referenced as the capture group. regex : `/\([http://mydmncd].*\)"/g`. Which can then be later referenced as `\1`. The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) has more to say.

Comment: here is what I am trying to do. Match the url and replace it with another url. But my regex is matching till last double quote instead of first double quote

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
/^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/
```

for example? Does it suit your needs?